# track-changes-suggestion-data-mismatch error how to debug

Tags: ckeditor5

I have been currently following the [Documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/collaboration/track-changes/track-changes-integration.html#implementation) and getting the `track-changes-suggestion-data-mismatch` error, i am unsure how to debug it, any help would be much appreciated.

I have compared both the data(html) which is generated by CKEditor and also the data fetched from the server, there is no difference.

If anyone can shed some light as to which data the error is talking about it would be great.

Comment: In my case the `authorId` for some reason was different on the suggestion object loaded from the server and `authorId` in`<suggestion-start name="insertion:{suggestionId}:{authorId}>` tag inside document html. Don't know how it could happen though.

Comment: Solved the issue thanks a lot